# Table is not altering

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have two tables in my wordpress database.

```
$table_name1='objectives';

$table_name2='implementation-how';
```

Now I want to alter these tables.So I am using "dbDelta" function to alter these tables.My $table_name1 is altered successfully,but $table_name2 is not altering.Can anyone suggest what is I am missing.I am using following code

```
$table_name1='objectives';
    $sql= "CREATE TABLE $table_name1 (
    `objectiveID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `catID` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `objective` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     `evalMeasure` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`objectiveID`)
    ) $charset_collate;";
    dbDelta( $sql );
```

and

```
$table_name2='implementation-how';  
     $sql= "CREATE TABLE $table_name2 (
    `howID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `strategyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `how` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
     ADD `is_default` int(11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      ADD `userID` int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (`howID`)
    ) $charset_collate;";
     dbDelta( $sql );
```

Comment: Is there more to your code?

Comment: well i am not a profesional at mysql ,but if both of those queries are executed at the same time it could be due to  $sql (both have the same "variable") ,or i could be mistaken,change the $sql for the #table_name2 and give it a go?

Answer (score 0):

check this . when creating tables ,table name can't use  '-' symbols (reserved symbols)

```
$table_name2='implementationhow';  
     $sql= "CREATE TABLE $table_name2 (
    `howID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `strategyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `how` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
     `is_default` int(11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
     `userID` int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (`howID`)
    ) ";

dbDelta( $sql );
```

Comment: I  had changed table name to 'implementationhow'

Comment: but when i am creating table using mysql dump file with 'implementation-how',it's successfully created.

Comment: we had changed the table name to 'implementationhow'  so we need to replace the table name .    'implementation-how' to 'implementationhow' .

Comment: if you globally declared the table name, then change it there.

Comment: I want to say i changed table name in all placed but it's not working.

Comment: Sorry, I checked it agin, if i change table name it's works.But is there any way without change table name

Comment: using reserved symbols in table name is not a good method and mysql not allow it . You should change the table name.

Answer (score 0):

use that code

```
  $table_name2='implementation_how';  
    CREATE TABLE $table_name2 (
    `howID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `strategyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `how` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
     `is_default` int(11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `userID` int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (`howID`) ) ";
dbDelta( $sql );
```

Comment: what is you changed in it, I think this is same code

Comment: yes but use underscore in table name or other changes in your code add keyword remove

Comment: if i change table name it's works.But is there any way without change table name